# Incorrect output for a program that is supposed to flip digits

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that when you input 1 or 0, it will flip it to the opposite number, and append it to the end. It should then repeat this process with the entire number.

Example:

Input - 1

Iterations - 3

Expected output - 10010110

Actual output - 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string num;
std::string futureNum;
int iterations = 1;
int main()
{

    std::cout << "number to start with (1 or 0)";
    getline (std::cin, num);
    std::cout<<"\nIterations:";
    std::cin>>iterations;
    while (iterations > 0) {
        for(int i = 0;i<=num.length();i++)
        {
            futureNum[i]=((num[i]-48)^1)+48;
        }

        num.append(futureNum);
        futureNum="";
        iterations--;
    }
    std::cout<<num<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `futureNum[i]` doesn't extend the `string` if `i` exceeds the bounds of the string. It's undefined behavior, you are not allowed to try to access elements beyond the end of the string.

Comment: I thought std::string could expand on it's own? Or that it at least allocated a lot of memory?

Comment: ***I thought std::string could expand on it's own?*** It does not change size with `operator[]` you need to tell it to resize. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/

Comment: ***Or that it at least allocated a lot of memory?*** No. It does not allocate a lot of memory.

Comment: @user1475369 It can't but not by using `operator[]`. Try `futureNum.push_back(((num[i]-48)^1)+48);` instead. `push_back` is one of the members that will automatically grow the string as needed. Take a moment to familiarize with the features of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @user1475369 Change `futureNum[i]=((num[i]-48)^1)+48;` to `futureNum.at(i)=((num[i]-48)^1)+48;` and watch the sparks fly.  Those "sparks" are what others have already described to you.

Comment: ^ please use `'0'` instead of `48`

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the program by changing `futureNum[i]=((num[i]-48)^1)+48;` to `futureNum.push_back(((num[i]-48)^1)+48);`, then replacing `futureNum="";` to `futureNum.clear();`

Thanks to François Andrieux